# Is there any java library for domain lookup?

Tags: java

Is there any free java library using which i can convert IP to domain and vice-versa?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any extra libraries - it's all in the standard JRE. Look at `InetAddress.getByName`, `InetAddress.getByAddress`, `InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName` etc.

Comment: I am not sure how true it is, but i read somewhere `InetAddress.getHostName()` will take almost 5 sec to tell you that it is unable to resolve the IP.

Comment: The resolve will not be any faster than the underlying system's configured DNS. If the IP can't be reverse lookup in DNS, it will fail. The 5 seconds shouldn't be java's fault, but the time it takes to do the DNS.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to track down the actual geographic location, you can use http://www.maxmind.com/app/java - but it costs money for the data.

Comment: Just as long as we're clear on that this is not an alternative to Jon Skeet's solution. DNS name <-> IP address is very different to Geographic location <-> IP address.